# How to use Progress Bar with my Functions

Tags: c#, windows

Its my code, Can anyone please suggest me how i can put my progress bar so it can perform progress with function simultaneously..
i used progress bar in my application.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    canaryTimer.Start();
    canaryTimer.Interval = 1000;
    canaryTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(canaryTimer_Tick);
    PickDatafromTextFile();
    CallRichtextbox();
    GenerateExcel();
    DeleteExcelRows();
    SplitDateandTime();
    SortDateandTime();
    CombineDataoftwoExcel();
    UpdateExcelFile();
}


private void canaryTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        canaryProgressBar.Value=i;
    }
}
```

Comment: you surely have a running process ?=! that you want to monitor. Usually you would have a counter that represents your progress. This value (simply said) would be added to you `progressbar.Value`

Comment: i used different code but no one is working. @LaneL

Comment: would be good to show some and explain what errors you get

Comment: I use timer also with it. see my edit code

Comment: @MongZhu- I am not getting any error. But progress bar start when my last function completed and end.

Comment: the thing is that your timer runs for 100 seconds, apparently all you functions are finished already by then

Comment: if the code you have posted is your entire process that you want to monitor then try the solution by Brecht C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple suggestion:
Update your Progressbar from within the Button1_Click after each function completes.
Assuming your myProgressBar.Value is initialized with 0;
Example:

```
                PickDatafromTextFile();
                myProgressBar.Value += 14;
                CallRichtextbox();
                myProgressBar.Value += 14;
                GenerateExcel();
                myProgressBar.Value += 14;
                DeleteExcelRows();
                myProgressBar.Value += 14;
                SplitDateandTime();
                myProgressBar.Value += 14;
                SortDateandTime();
                myProgressBar.Value += 14;
                CombineDataoftwoExcel();
                myProgressBar.Value += 14;
                UpdateExcelFile();
                myProgressBar.Value = 100;
```

I know this isn't the correct way to do so. But for a simple task like this any other method would seem overkill to me.

Comment: Thanks Brecht. This is what i want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the point of your question... If you want to load a textfile and than work with the information, you have to check out how much percent of the work is done. after that, you can increase the progressbar with this command:

```
      progressBar1->Increment(1);
```

also you can set it to a value

```
      progressBar1->Value = 5;
```

Comment: don't forget to set minimum and maximum :)

Comment: In my code, i used what u suggest.

Comment: hmm, but you should not use it inside a timer step... because you don't know how much time you need... or do you?

Comment: ahh... I think your problem is, that at the time when you run the readtxt code, the timer does nothing... I think you have to load in a different thread

Comment: I think the `Timer` runs in a separate thread, like the `Stopwatch` when `start()`is executed